# ASP.NET MVC 5 Identity change password as administrator without email

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

If you have an ASP.NET MVC 5 site configured **without** email confirmation, how can a password reset be performed by an administrator?

I can write a console app which resets the password in the database, but that seems inefficient. Also, the old `aspnet_Membership_ResetPassword` sproc has no counterpart in the new identity system.

Comment: All you have to do is update the password field in the database (after hashing / encrypting it of course). There is no sproc necessary, you can do it in C#. What have you tried?

Comment: Yes I realize I can do it in C#, but my sysadmin can't. Short of writing him a tool to do the hashing, I don't see another option.

Comment: You should probably add a feature to the MVC site which will allow authorized users (sysadmin) to perform this action from a web page.

Comment: Or maybe just a controller action that responds to a GET request with a password to hash in the URL. The sysadmin can just paste the response into `AspNetUsers.PasswordHash`, no? Does `SecurityStamp` matter?

Comment: Yes, each time the user data changes, the security stamp should get a new Guid.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve. You still have to get the password to the user somehow, so will you be emailing them a generated password instead of the standard "follow a link in a email to a page that lets you pick a new password" approach?

Also, are you talking about specifically resetting one user's password or resetting *all* user passwords. If the latter, then a console app is the way to go. If the former, you can simply add a view to some backend that's only accessible to admins that let's them perform this function for a specific user.

As far as generating some random password goes, you're on your own there, but a simple web search should turn up plenty of methods to choose from.

Word to the wise, though, the email confirmation approach is standard for a reason. It provides a relatively secure way to allow a user to regain access to their account when they can't remember their password. It's most important feature, though, is that it forces the user to actually change their password, whereas with a provided password, random or not, users will actually *use* that password, rather than take the time to manually change it after logging in - especially with password managers these days. That means if you sent that password via email, or wrote it on a sticky or whatever, you now have a huge gaping security hole.

Comment: I'm talking specifically about a sysadmin resetting the password of a single user. No email.